# Yii ActiveForm: Loading a form via jQuery.load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii

I have a button which triggers a $("#element").load event. This button and #element is inside 'page A'

a Yii activeform is loaded inside that element (lets call this 'page B'). This activeform is configured to have ajaxvalidation=true. This obviously fails because jquery.yiiactiveform.js file won't be loaded when calling the activeform because yiiactiveform.js file needed to be in the main layout (page A) and puts the jquery.yiiactiveform.js reference in there.

One solution is to pre-load the activeform JS on 'page a' via:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('yiiactiveform');
```

and have the corresponding JS code which binds the form actions inside 'page a' too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
$('#register-form').yiiactiveform({'validateOnSubmit':true,....,'enableAjaxValidation':true}]});
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Another one is to have these JS calls inside page B, but that would mean putting head tags inside page B. My Page B right now contains only the form element, no html, no body tags, just the form tag because we don't need it anyway, this page is only accessible by load()ing it inside page A.

However this approach isn't really great. It's like manually binding the appropriate JS calls in the loaded form, defeats the purpose of the framework. I Think it would have work if Yii activeform JS supports jquery's on() or live() methods.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Found it. The renderPartial() call to page B must be:

    $this->renderPartial('viewfile', array('var'=> $val),false,true);

4th param must be set to true. With this, it processes the view file and inserts the corresponding JS codes inside it.

Comment: great that you found your solution, you can answer your own question, and accept that answer.

Comment: Thanks. but there are time limits on new accounts like mine.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The renderPartial() call to page B must be:

```
$this->renderPartial('viewfile', array('var'=> $val),false,true);
```

4th param must be set to true. With this, it processes the view file and inserts the corresponding JS codes inside it.

Comment: My issue with this is that jQuery is loaded twice